# How do I access my struct's elements in different if statements?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, initialization, declaration

Apologies if this is a really dumb question.

I have declared and initialised a struct array here (just above the for loop);

```
printf("\n>>>");
    scanf( "%s" , &CurrentCommand);

    if (strcmp(CurrentCommand, "bang") == 0)
    {
        Clear();
        printf("Enter the number of stars to be created: ");
        scanf("%d", &NumberOfStars);

        struct StarsStruct *Stars = malloc(sizeof(struct StarsStruct) * NumberOfStars);

        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfStars; i++)
        {
            r1 = rand() % (60 + 1 - 0) + 0;
            r2 = rand() % (30 + 1 - 0) + 0;

            Stars[i].SerialNumber = i;
            Stars[i].x = r1;
            Stars[i].y = r2;

            Plot(r1, r2, '.');
        }

    }
```

I have accessed the elements I need in the for loop, in the first IF statement, however I am no longer able to access them on my second IF loop, probably because "struct StarsStruct *Stars" was declared locally.

So how would I be able to access it in another if statement? Declaring it at the start doesn't work, because I guess creating the array with malloc has to be done in one go, with the declaration and initialisation.

To sum up, I want to access member of the Stars struct, in another IF statement I will create, Stars[1].SerialNumber and such. However I currently cannot.

Comment: You can still *define* the variable somewhere in a higher scope, but *initialize* it somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define your variable further up where it will be visible where it is needed.  You'll just need to initialize it to `NULL`, then you can later assign the result of `malloc` where you need to.

```
// define up here and initialize to NULL
struct StarsStruct *Stars = NULL;

printf("\n>>>");
scanf( "%s" , &CurrentCommand);

if (strcmp(CurrentCommand, "bang") == 0)
{
    Clear();
    printf("Enter the number of stars to be created: ");
    scanf("%d", &NumberOfStars);

    // assign here
    Stars = malloc(sizeof(struct StarsStruct) * NumberOfStars);

    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfStars; i++)
    {
        r1 = rand() % (60 + 1 - 0) + 0;
        r2 = rand() % (30 + 1 - 0) + 0;

        Stars[i].SerialNumber = i;
        Stars[i].x = r1;
        Stars[i].y = r2;

        Plot(r1, r2, '.');
    }

}
```